# How can I dispatch my variables to redux file with hooks

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks

```
const LoginContainer = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const onLoginClick = (e) => {
    dispatch(userLogin);
    dispatch(email);


  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className='content'>
        <SectionLogin
          onLoginClick={onLoginClick}
          setEmail={setEmail}
          setPassword={setPassword}
        />
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
export default LoginContainer;
```

I want to access email in redux file.in my redux file, I have wrote actions and types. Give are welcome if any further modification is required

**Redux Action file**

```
export const userLogin = async (dispatch, action) => {


  dispatch({ type: POST_LOGIN_DETAILS_START });

  try {
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/login', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        email: this.state.email,
        password: this.state.password,
      }),
    });
    const payload = await response.json();
    dispatch({ type: POST_LOGIN_DETAILS_SUCCESS, payload });


  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({ type: POST_LOGIN_DETAILS_FAIL });
  }
};
```

I want to access email and password in action file to send a post request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got the answer

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';    import SectionLogin from './LoginPage';    import { userLogin } from    './dux';
  const LoginContainer = () => {
const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
const dispatch = useDispatch();

const onLoginClick = (e) => {
  dispatch(userLogin);

  dispatch(userLogin(email));// should pass variables as argument to the function

};

return (
  <>
    <div className='content'>
      <SectionLogin
        onLoginClick={onLoginClick}
        setEmail={setEmail}
        setPassword={setPassword}
      />
    </div>
  </>

  );
}; 
export default LoginContainer;
```

**Redux Action file**

```
 export const userLogin = (email) => async (dispatch) => {  

    //have to access email inside userLogin function
 try {
     
 //code here
 }
 catch (error) {
 //code here
 };
```

This is the best method if you want to send data to the redux file, by passing the variable as an argument

Answer (score 1):

wrong: `dispatch(email)`
right: `dispatch({ type: 'YOUR_ACTION_IDENTIFIER', payload: email })`

see:

- [redux: dispatch an action](https://redux.js.org/api/store#dispatchaction)
- [react-redux: useDispatch()](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#usedispatch)

Comment: I was about to say that :)